# What are these red cocoons in my trees leaves?

Tags: trees, insects, diagnosis

The tree In my garden as lots of red cocoons on its leaves, I assume these are insects, do I need to be concerned or are they harmless?

[image]

Comment: I don't think those are coccoons.

Comment: Your local extension is probably the best place to go for this.  Oh - I see you are not in US - hopefully you have an agriculture office locally you can get advice from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here's some Insect advice from Penn State.](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/leaf-galls-maple)

In summary, it sounds like you have a mite problem for your tree (take note of the other trees, that looks like a maple leaf to which this insect is characteristic); they are "commonly referred to as eriophyid mites".

- "these galls are not harmful to the health of a tree. ... Feeding by eriophyid mites appears to stimulate the formation of galls on the upper and lower surface of the leaves... If many leaves on a tree are heavily infested, there may be some reduction in growth."
- "In general, leaf galls do not seriously affect the normal growth of a tree. Thus, chemical control is seldom suggested. If indicated, the best time to treat an infested tree ... is mid-April, before buds swell"
- [Note that these mites are predated by ladybugs green lacewings](http://www.fcps.edu/islandcreekes/ecology/maple_gall_mite.htm), so if you have an infestation of either of those these might be contributing in some way to that.

[image: Gall Mites nymphing it up on a maple leaf]